# Unable to send mails using Discourse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, discourse

I have docker installation of discourse from [this article](https://serversforhackers.com/video/installing-discourse-with-docker). Discourse is working fine but I am unable to send mails.

I have tried [this article](https://meta.discourse.org/t/troubleshooting-email-on-a-new-discourse-install/16326/2) for troubleshooting with no lucks.

my settings are.

```
## TODO: The mailserver this Discourse instance will use
  DISCOURSE_SMTP_ADDRESS: smtp.zoho.com    # (mandatory)
  DISCOURSE_SMTP_PORT: 587                        # (optional)
  DISCOURSE_SMTP_USER_NAME: xxxxx@xxxxxx.in     # (optional)
  DISCOURSE_SMTP_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxx            # (optional)
 ##
```

when I check production logs it shows Unprocessable entry.

```
Started POST "/admin/email/test" for 106.51.227.84 at 2016-10-09 10:36:28 +0000
Processing by Admin::EmailController#test as */*
  Parameters: {"email_address"=>"geekceeaim@gmail.com"}

Sent mail to geekceeaim@gmail.com (1430.7ms)
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1871ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn’t really feel on topic on Stack Overflow I’m afraid.

Comment: Did you really do everything mentioned in that article - check logs, etc.? Is there anything in the logs?

Comment: Yes I did... the logs are following  Started POST "/admin/email/test" for 106.51.227.84 at 2016-10-09 10:36:28 +0000
Processing by Admin::EmailController#test as */*
  Parameters: {"email_address"=>"geekceeaim@gmail.com"}

Sent mail to geekceeaim@gmail.com (1430.7ms)
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1871ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)

Comment: Not sure about the 422 error, but do you have mail server logs, too? Those may be more relevant to what’s going on with the message